# On matrices with trace value zero

Tags: matrices

I would like to ask you something regarding the trace of a matrix (the value of the diagonal after adding all its members, a value which is said to remain constant independently from base changes):

Do matrices with trace value zero constitute a (sub)group? If so, which properties tell them apart from matrices with non-zero trace values? Should a matrix with diagonal entries such as , say, [2, -3, 1], group together with that showing [0,0,0]?

I am particularly interested in those cases in which all the members of the diagonal equal zero. Do they have interesting algebraic properties as compared with the other zero trace matrices and the nonzero matrices altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Useful Point: Skew Symmetric matrices have trace 0. (in fact, all diagonal elements zero.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Other_properties has useful information towards it.

Comment: If you consider the $K$-vector space of square matrices $M_n(K)$, then the trace is a linear form $\operatorname{Tr}:M_n(K) \longrightarrow K$, hence the space of traceless matrices is the kernel of this form. This implies that it is a subspace of $M_n(K)$ of dimension $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the group question, try computing the square of the $2\times2$ matrix describing a quarter turn.

The traceless matrices do form a Lie algebra (the bracket is the commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$). In fact the commutator of *any* pair of square matrices is traceless.

There is nothing particularly interesting about matrices with all diagonal entries zero, since that condition is not invariant under change of basis (while the value of the trace is).

Comment: How come the zero diaginal entries condition not be invariant? As you correctly state, the value fo the trace remains constant. All diagonal entries being zero means the trace value is zero, and that zero value will remain invariant across changes of basis. Do you mean that value would remain zero while the zero entries rearrange themselves with different values which nonetheless yield zero as their sum? Could you provide a specific example withchange of base? Thanks.

Comment: Is it fair to say that traceless matrices represent a scenario where the group does not undergo any movement whatsoever?

Comment: @JavierArias: For instance the permutation matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$ has all diagonal entries zero, but it is diagonalisable with diagonal form $(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix})$, which does not have all diagonal entries zero (though it is still traceless).  Diagonalisation is obtained by an appropriate change of basis.

Comment: @JavierArias: For your second comment, I don't know what you mean by "group does not undergo any movement whatsoever"? What group, which action? What one can say is that for the adjoint (conjugation) action of $GL(n)$ on itself, the derivatives (which is what the Lie bracket gives) are always in the direction of the codimension$~1$ subspace of the tangent space given by the traceless matrices. This does not mean the derivative is zero; certainly things do undergo change.

Comment: Well, a Lie Algebra represents a Lie Group, right? A continuous movement group, right? I am sorry, I am not a mathematician, just someone trying to understand certain structures in order to better understand linguistics, for instance; someone who relies on books such as the Encyclopedia of Mathematics by Kolmogorov or on Jules Vuillemin's chapter on Lie in his "La philosophie de l'algèbre". I make an effort to understand, but probably have many formal lacunae. Sorry if that is the case.

Comment: You can think of a Lie algebra as a kind of derivative of a Lie group; the group determines the algebra, but not conversely. More precisely the Lie algebra is the _tangent space_ to the group at the identity element (so it models very small deviations from the identity), and it is equipped with a structure (Lie bracket) that corresponds to the derivative of conjugation $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$; this measures at an infinitesimal scale the non-commutativity of the group (since for commutative groups conjugation is just the identity).

Comment: Is it fair to consider the group as possibly undegoing movement (for instance, rotation, or sliding), while keeping itself topologically compact (no modification of the initial distances between two given points, or, even better, keeping adjacency conditions between any two given elements?

Comment: By the way, isn't the term traceless matrix misleading? I think a zero value does not entail being traceless. Traceless matrix are those non quadratic matrices which do not allow for a diagonal value, right? I am saying this because as a linguist I would like to keep a difference between a structure having left a "mute" trace behind after its movement, from a structure not having moved and therefore not having left any trace whatsoever.....Does it make sense to you what I am saying??

Comment: @JavierArias: linguistically speaking you are right: a traceless matrix is a matrix that has disappeared without leaving a trace. But since it is rare to discuss those in mathematics, it is not unheard of to call matrices with trace zero [traceless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#traceless). But it is true that nobody would call a matrix with determinant zero "determinantless". By comparison, many theorems that state that some quantity is zero are called "vanishing theorems" (even though the theorems, and the people they are called after, remain).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22840/discussion-between-javier-arias-and-marc-van-leeuwen).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Wouldn't it make sense to talk about non-quadratic matrices as being traceless, thus keeping the term just for that purpose? It may be "deformation profesionelle" on my part, but anyway.....

Comment: This is not exactly what I am pursuing, but it provides a nice view on what can be done for the study of language with such tools: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/GraphGrammarsLing.pdf